# How to get list of all sites in Wordpress Multisite Network?

Tags: wordpress

I need some php request for get list of all sites in wp-network. Is it possible?

Comment: Show some research that you've done. People aren't going to want to help you if you don't demonstrate a willingness to help yourself.

Comment: It's kind of code, that can't be reachable by logic. By the way, I didnt think about codex. And I really thankful to Firefox for answer, because even now I understand that I wouldn't find it in codex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
 <?php wp_get_sites( $args ); ?>
```

Examples ,for bellow v 3.0

```
<?php
$blog_list = get_blog_list( 0, 'all' );
foreach ($blog_list AS $blog) {
    echo 'Blog '.$blog['blog_id'].': '.$blog['domain'].$blog['path'].'<br />';
}
?>
```

Comment: The problem with "get_blog_list" function is that, if one or more sites were not set as public (in the network's sites list), they will not appear in the list produced by this function.

Comment: Use `wp_get_sites() ` instead.   https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_blog_list/

Comment: @Firefog That function `wp_get_sites` is correct but your link goes to a deprecated function... here is the correct link: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/

Answer (score 11):

As of WP 4.6 there is a new [function to query sites](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_sites/), `get_sites($query_arg)` which is a parallel to the familiar `get_posts($query_args)` used for retrieving posts,

```
$blogs = get_sites();
foreach( $blogs as $b ){
    $b->blog_id 
    //Do stuff
}
```

**NOTE**: As pointed out by [@guido-walter-pettinari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2972183/guido-walter-pettinari) in the comment below, `get_sites()` is a front for instantiating a new `WP_Sites_query` object which sets some [default query parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_site_query/__construct/), including the `'number'` of sites to return to 100!

Comment: BE CAREFUL: `get_sites()` will only list the first 100 sites! To get more sites (say, 500), use `get_sites( [ "number" => 500 ] );`. Of course, if you have more than 500 websites, it might be a good idea to use paging :-)

Comment: excellent point, will add it to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Using WordPress functions is a bit problematic, when you aim compatibility with all multisite versions:

- **get_blog_list** is not only deprecated, but it does not return sites not flagged as public either. Strangely, the oficial documentation hasn't warned us about that (you discover only when your code fails).
- **get_sites**, in contrast, works only in WP 4.6.0 or higher

I prefer using the following code, which is compatible with all WordPress versions (as of 3.0.0, of course), and returns all sites of the installation (even the archived ones, deactivated ones, etc.):

```
global $wpdb;  
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT blog_id, domain, path FROM $wpdb->blogs ORDER BY blog_id" );
```

If you want to filter your results, not showing the archived ones, deactivated ones and spam sites, you have to indicate that in the query as follows:

```
global $wpdb;
$blogs = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT blog_id, domain, path FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE archived = '0' AND deleted = '0' AND spam = '0' ORDER BY blog_id" );
```

Note: `$blogs` array is an object collection; you will have to build your own site list with the informations that comes inside every object (id, path, domain) that is more appropriate for you, as exemplified in *Firefog* and *Aurovrata* answers.

Comment: Just a note that they did finally add a deprecation notice re: `get_blog_list` function on the developer reference: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_blog_list/

Comment: Yes, as well as wp_get_sites

Answer (score 0):

In the usual way, you will be unable to get the blog name. To fetch blog names, you can use this little hack as follows.

```
$blog_list = get_blog_list(0, 'all');
foreach ($blog_list as $blog) {
    switch_to_blog( $blog['blog_id'] );
    $option = 'blogname';
    $value = get_option( $option );
    echo $value . '<br />';
    restore_current_blog();
}
```

Also, you can use the following alternative method to get the same result by calling the database directly.

```
global $wpdb;
foreach ($wpdb->get_results("SELECT blog_id, domain, path FROM $wpdb->blogs WHERE archived = '0' AND deleted = '0' AND spam = '0' ORDER BY blog_id") as $key => $blog) {
    switch_to_blog( $blog->blog_id );
    $option = 'blogname';
    $value = get_option( $option );
    echo $value . '<br />';
    restore_current_blog();
}
```